# Change the default settings of a print queue

Tags: .net, powershell, printing

We're creating a script that collects user input from an Excel file. Each row represents one printer with its specific settings. So for each row we need to create a print queue on the print server.

We're struggling with setting the default settings for the printer So that when a user on the network adds the printer to his/her system, the settings are taken over from the queue on the print server.

**Example with `PageOrientation`**

On the print queue on the server we select `Properties > Preferences > Basic` where we set `PageOrientation = Landscape`. These settings are used when a user installs the network printer on his/her system:

[image: Default printing preferences]

Within PowerShell we tried to request the value for `PageOrientation` and expect to find `Landscape` but always get `Portrait`.

**Some code:**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Printing
$permissions = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministrateServer
$queueperms = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministratePrinter
$server = New-Object System.Printing.PrintServer -argumentList $permissions
$queues = @($server.GetPrintQueues())
$Printer = $queues.Where( {$_.Name -eq $testPrinter.PrinterName})

# Results all in 'Portrait' not 'Landscape'
$Printer.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageOrientation
$Printer.DefaultPrintTicket.PageOrientation
$Printer.PropertiesCollection.UserPrintTicket.value.PageOrientation
$Printer.PropertiesCollection.DefaultPrintTicket.value.PageOrientation
$Printer.UserPrintTicket.PageOrientation
```

Trying to use `Set-PrintConfiguration` for changing the default tray does reflect a change when checked with `Get-PrinterConfiguration`, but it's not visible in the GUI and also not applied as a default when a user adds the network printer.

```
$PrintConfiguration = Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $PrinterName
$PrintTicketXML = [XML]$PrintConfiguration.PrintTicketXML
$CurrentTray = ($PrintTicketXML.PrintTicket.Feature).where( {$_.name -eq 'psk:JobInputBin'}).option.name
$NewTray = if ($Tray -eq 'AutoSelect') {"psk:$Tray"} else {"ns0000:$Tray"}
$UpdatedPrintTicketXML = $PrintConfiguration.PrintTicketXML -Replace "$CurrentTray", "$NewTray"
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $PrinterName -PrintTicketXml $UpdatedPrintTicketXML
```

Where can we find these default properties like `Default tray`, `Paper type`, ... and most importantly set their values?

Comment: I couldn't work out a way to set these for Konica printers when I looked into it a few years back, their support didn't have any idea either. Watching this question to see if anyone else had any luck!

Answer (score 2):

Hello everyone my answer may be too late but I post anyway if it can help someone, You can use KMDRVSET a cmd control tool from Konica minolta. it is available on the Konica InfoHub, get closer to a KM technician if you do not have access to InfoHub.
[Manual](http://www.audentia-gestion.fr/konicaminolta/PDF/KMDRVSET%20Administrator%20Guide.Rev.12.pdf)